# iOS - ionic angular download pdf

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pdf-generation, capacitor

I have a PHP service that generates a PDF. In my method I have the following code that works when I run it in browser:

```js
runReport(): void {
  this.loading = true;
  this.reportService.runReport(this.body)
    .pipe(finalize(() => this.loading = false))
    .subscribe(response => {
      const file = new Blob([response.body], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      window.open(fileURL);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = fileURL;
      a.target = '_blank';
      a.download = '-redacted filename-.pdf';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
    });
}
```

However, when I use capacitor to generate the Xcode and publish the app to my phone it isn't working. I can see where my loading spinner comes up and then goes away, but the PDF is never downloaded.

Is there a different way to automatically download the file to the device?

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I use capacitor to generate the Xcode and publish the
> app to my phone it isn't working.

Obviously it will not work because there is no such thing as `window.open(fileURL);` on phones. What you need to do is download your pdf physically on the phone. Then use classic apps that comes with the phone to open / view downloaded pdf files.

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
   const url = "http://example.com/myfile.pdf";
   fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + directory + "/" + "one.pdf", false, {
     headers: {
       Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
     }
   }).then((entry) => {
     console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
     const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
       title: "PDF File",
     };
         this.previewAnyFile.preview(entry.toURL())
       .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
       .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
 
   }, (error) => {
     console.log("Error: ", error);
 
   });
```

Above code will download any file from given HTTP address and save it on phone. Then [previewAnyFile](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/preview-any-file) will use currently installed document viewers to display the downloaded pdf.

Comment: I guess it is not that obvious to me because my understanding was that ionic used a modified in-app browser to render the content. Could you point me in the direction of what I can use to download the PDF?

Comment: Updated my answer with actual code you can use.